# Show that metric $d=max\{2d_1,d_2\}$ is topologically equivalent to both $d_1$ and $d_2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent metrics
show that $d=max\{2d_1,d_2\}$ is topologically
equivalent to both $d_1$ and $d_2$

I can show one direction$(\tau _1\subseteq\tau )$ by choosing $\delta=min\{r_1,r_2\}$,
but to prove other direction $(\tau \subseteq\tau _1)$, 
how should I choose $\delta$?

Comment: Does $\delta$ have any significance other that being a variable indicating a formula?

Comment: $r_1, r_2, \delta$ are radius of corresponding open balls at $\tau _1, \tau _2, \tau$

Comment: If $B_1(x,r_1)\subseteq \tau_1$ I'am choosing $\delta$ like that so $B(x,\delta)\subseteq B_1(x,r_1)$

Answer (score 0):

One needs to show that $d,d_1,d_2$ all generate the same topology.

It is clear that $\max(d_1,d_2) \le \max(2 d_1, d_2) \le 2 \max(d_1,d_2)$, so $\max(2d_1,d_2)$ and $\max(d_1,d_2)$ are strongly equivalent and hence generate the same topology. It is slightly easier to deal with $\max(d_1,d_2)$.

Let $d_*=\max(d_1,d_2)$ and let $B_*(x,\delta)$ be the $\delta$ ball around $x$ using $d_*$. Similarly with $d_k$ and $B_k(x,\delta)$.

Since $d_1 \le d_*, d_2 \le d_*$ we see that given $\delta>0$ that
$d_*(x,y) \le \delta$ implies $d_k(x,y) \le \delta$ and hence
$B_*(x,\delta) \subset B_k(x,\delta)$.

For the other direction, choose $\delta>0$. Now choose $\delta' \le \delta$ such that $B_2(x,\delta') \subset B_1(x,\delta)$. This is possible
since $d_1,d_2$ are topologically equivalent.

Suppose $y \in B_2(x,\delta')$, then $d_2(x,y) < \delta' \le \delta$ and
$d_1(x,y) < \delta$, so $d_*(x,y) < \delta$ and so $B_2(x,\delta') \subset B_*(x,\delta)$.

The same approach with $d_1,d_2$ reversed shows that we can find a $\delta''>0$
so that $B_1(x,\delta'') \subset B_*(x,\delta)$.

Hence $d_*$ is topologically equivalent to each of the $d_k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still I don't understand the second direction. What is $\delta$ and how do you compare it to $\delta'$ and $\delta"$

Comment: To show that metrics $a,b$ are topologically equivalent you need to show that for any $x$ and for any $r>0$ that there are $r',r''>0$ such that $B_a(x,r') \subset B_b(x,r)$ and $B_b(x,r'') \subset B_a(x,r)$. In the second direction, I start with some $\delta>0$ (I edited the answer slightly to clarify) and then find radii that work for the $d_k$.

Comment: So, if I understand this right, you are not trying to find $r'$ and $r"$, you are just using the fact that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent, and that they exist?

Comment: Well, the fact that the $d_k$ are topologically equivalent means that given some $r>0$ I can find some appropriate $r',r''$ (that relates the $ B_1,B_2$ balls).

Comment: I believe I got it now. Thank you

Comment: @39fm5: Actually, I think I have made it more complicated than necessary. I will simplify if I can.

Comment: @39fm5: I have simplified the proof a bit. I was trying to be cute earlier to find a $r>0$ that worked for both $d_1,d_2$ simultaneously, but there is no point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the open ball about $x_0$ radius $r>0$ wrt the metric $d$. We want to find $r'>0$ so that the open ball about $x_0$ radius $r'$ wrt the metric $d_1$ lies inside $B$.

Since $d_1,d_2$ are equivalent we can find $r_2>0$ such that $d_1(x,x_0)<r_2$ implies $d_2(x,x_0)<r$. Take $r'=\min(r/2,r_2)$, then $d_1(x,x_0)<r'$ implies $2d_1(x,x_0)<r$ and $d_2(x,x_0)<r$ and hence $d(x,x_0)=\max(2d_1(x,x_0),d_2(x,x_0))<r$.

You already showed the converse, so we have established that $d$ is (topologically) equivalent to $d_1$.

Exactly similar arguments show that $d$ is equivalent to $d_2$.